# Create pagination using while loop

Tags: php, html, while-loop, pagination

I want to create pagination using while loop.

I already show data limit to 10. But I have no idea how to show the pagination number in time calculation below.

Any solutions?

Thank you.

```
<table border=0 width=800 cellspacing=1 cellpadding=2>
  <tr height=22>
    <td align=center bgColor=red width=5%>No.</td>
    <td align=center bgColor=red width=15%>Date</td>
    <td align=center bgColor=red width=20%>Time</td>
    <td align=center bgColor=red width=15%>Status</td>
  </tr>

<?php
    $start_hour = "05";
    $start_min = "00";
    $end_hour = "15";
    $end_min = "00";
    
    $start = new DateTime("$start_hour$start_min");
    $end = new DateTime("$end_hour$end_min");   
    $article_num = 1;
    $resultPerPage = 10;
    $pageNum = 1;
    
    while (($start < $end) && ($article_num <= $resultPerPage)) {
        $start_time = $start->format('H:i');
        $key_time = $start->format('Hi');
        $start->modify('+10 minute');
        $end_time = $start->format('H:i');
        
        $link_reserv = "#";
        
        echo ("<tr>");
        echo ("<td align=center>$article_num</td>");
        echo ("<td align=center>2013/12/16</td>");
        echo ("<td align=center>$start_time - $end_time</td>");
        echo ("<td align=center><input type=button value=Book&nbsp;Now onclick=\"window.location.href='$link_reserv';\"></td>");
        echo ("</tr>");
        
        $article_num++;
    }
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Hint: `pages = floor(total / recordsPerPage)`.

Comment: Just get the total_num_rows and divide by how many records to be displayed in a page

Comment: I already get number of pages from this `while (($start < $end)) ...` I remove the `($article_num <= $resultPerPage)`, and the pages number successfully i get. And one problem is. How to limit the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

[Full CODE](http://www.crackerworld.in/2013/03/pagination-in-php.html)

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$sdb = mysql_select_db("pagination", $conn);

$tableName = "emp_details"; //page name
$targetpage = "pagination.php";
$limit = 3; //limit of dispaly

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tableName";
$total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
$total_pages = $total_pages[num];

$stages = 3;
$page = mysql_escape_string($_GET['page']);
if ($page) {
    $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;
} else {
    $start = 0;
}

// Get page data
$sel = mysql_query("select * FROM $tableName LIMIT $start, $limit");
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($sel)) {
    $id = $row1['emp_id'];
    $name = $row1['emp_name'];
    $doj = $row1['doj'];
    $experince = $row1['experince'];
    $salary = $row1['salary'];
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td height="20"><?php echo $id; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $doj; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $experince ?>year</td>
        <td><?php echo $salary ?></td>

    </tr>
<?php } ?>
<tr>
    <td colspan="5">
        <?php

        // Initial page num setup
        if ($page == 0) {
            $page = 1;
        }
        $prev = $page - 1;
        $next = $page + 1;
        $lastpage = ceil($total_pages / $limit);
        $LastPagem1 = $lastpage - 1;


        $paginate = '';
        if ($lastpage > 1) {

            $paginate .= "<div class='paginate'>";
            // Previous
            if ($page > 1) {
                $paginate .= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$prev'>previous</a>";
            } else {
                $paginate .= "<span class='disabled'>previous</span>";
            }


            // Pages
            if ($lastpage < 7 + ($stages * 2)) // Not enough pages to breaking it up
            {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++) {
                    if ($counter == $page) {
                        $paginate .= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                    } else {
                        $paginate .= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";
                    }
                }
            } elseif ($lastpage > 5 + ($stages * 2)) // Enough pages to hide a few?
            {
                // Beginning only hide later pages
                if ($page < 1 + ($stages * 2)) {
                    for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($stages * 2); $counter++) {
                        if ($counter == $page) {
                            $paginate .= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                        } else {
                            $paginate .= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";
                        }
                    }
                    $paginate .= "...";
                    $paginate .= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$LastPagem1'>$LastPagem1</a>";
                    $paginate .= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a>";
                } // Middle hide some front and some back
                elseif ($lastpage - ($stages * 2) > $page && $page > ($stages * 2)) {
                    $paginate .= "<a href='$targetpage?page=1'>1</a>";
                    $paginate .= "<a href='$targetpage?page=2'>2</a>";
                    $paginate .= "...";
                    for ($counter = $page - $stages; $counter <= $page + $stages; $counter++) {
                        if ($counter == $page) {
                            $paginate .= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                        } else {
                            $paginate .= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";
                        }
                    }
                    $paginate .= "...";
                    $paginate .= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$LastPagem1'>$LastPagem1</a>";
                    $paginate .= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a>";
                } // End only hide early pages
                else {
                    $paginate .= "<a href='$targetpage?page=1'>1</a>";
                    $paginate .= "<a href='$targetpage?page=2'>2</a>";
                    $paginate .= "...";
                    for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($stages * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++) {
                        if ($counter == $page) {
                            $paginate .= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                        } else {
                            $paginate .= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // Next
            if ($page < $counter - 1) {
                $paginate .= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$next'>next</a>";
            } else {
                $paginate .= "<span class='disabled'>next</span>";
            }

            $paginate .= "</div>";


        }
        echo $total_pages . ' Results';
        // pagination
        echo $paginate;
        ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
```